# Tkinter using a joystick to navigate through buttons

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, joystick

For my graduation project I am making a Arcade GUI with Python 3.7 and tkinter.

What I am stuck on currently is if there is a possibilty to use a (USB) Joystick to navigate through the buttons.

What I mean by this is when the joystick goes down it goes to the button below it, is that possible. I appreciate all help i can get!

Thank you

Comment: ***navigate through the buttons***: This require only to step through the` Button` in the Layout container (`Frame`)

Comment: Assuming that the joystick emits standard events, yes, it should be possible. You will need to determine what events get triggered by the joystick.